# Laurent series of $\frac{e^z}{z^2+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series, cauchy-product

I cant  figure out the laurent series of the following function.

Let $f(z)= \frac{e^z}{z^2+1} $ and $|z|\gt 1$

$$\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^{-2n-2}$$

and

$$e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}$$

$$e^z*\frac{1}{z^2+1} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^nz^{-2n-2}*\frac{z^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}$$

How can I go from here ?

Comment: Maybe try breaking it up into two fractions first. So factor the exponential out and then break up the fraction.

Comment: For your fist serie i think it is $\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^{2n}$.

Comment: @snowman I can break up the fraction into $\frac{i}{2(z+i)}-\frac{i}{2(z-i)}$ but I dont know how that would help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let
>
> \begin{align*}
>  f(z)&= \frac{e^z}{z^2+1}
> \end{align*}

We assume we need a Laurent expansion for all $|z|>1$  with center $z_0=0$.

> We    obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)&=\frac{e^z}{z^2+1}\\
> &=\frac{e^z}{z^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z^2}}\\
> &=\frac{e^z}{z^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{1}{z^{2k}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{z^j}{j!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{1}{z^{2k+2}}\\
> &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left(\sum_{{j-2k-2=n}\atop{j\geq 0;k\geq  0}}\frac{(-1)^k}{j!}\right)z^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left(\sum_{{j-2k=n}\atop{j\geq 0;k\geq  1}}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{j!}\right)z^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=K}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(n+2k)!}\right)z^n\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[Cauchy product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_infinite_series)*
- In (2) we shift the index $k$ by one
- In (3) we replace $j$ with $n+2k$ and since $j=n+2k\geq 0$ and $k\geq 1$ we have to set
  \begin{align*}
  K=\max\left\{1,-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right\}
  \end{align*}